# Apache URL RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

This is my first attempt at using RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

I have about 200 webpages the contain the text SPS or MENU (in UPPER or lower case) that I want to send to a webpage on another server.

I was thinking of something like this which I based on an example that I found in the Apache mod_rewrite documentation

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  (SPS|MENU) [NC]
RewriteRule  ^/$                 http://new-ws.org/new-ws.html  [L]
```

I am fairly familiar with Perl Regular Expressions, but could someone explain what `^/$` does?  I understand what `^` and `$` do.

As an example, if a user attempts to go to a webpage like http://old-ws.org/pub/TEST-SPS.html they should be redirected to a page on a different webserver.

Comment: And whats the target url should look like?

Answer (score 0):

It is the site root.

When you go to http://whatever.com, you actually request http://whatever.com/

That rule says redirect requests to the root `/`, and nothing else, given the anchors. The rule would send http://whatever.com/ to http://whatever.com/homepage.max.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of ^/$.  Makes sense, I just thought it was some trick than meant something else.  My requirement is not for the site root.  I have webpages residing under /pub with names like TEST-SPS.html, test1-sps.html, TEST2-MENU.html, test3-menu.html, etc and it is only those that I want to redirect.

Comment: @BrianG Please can you explain more by editing your question.